# Limit amount of instances a php script can run from cron

Tags: php, cron, limit, instance

I have a php script file that runs via cron jobs every 30 seconds and runs for a few minutes. I want to limit it so only a maximum amount of X instances can run at the same time, so if X amount of the script are already running the new launched script would exit and when one or more of the running script finishes the next cron will then be able to launch the script successfully.

I found some info about this but mostly for limiting to only 1 instance, like a mutex. So I was thinking on what solutions I could use to achieve what I need, here are some of the ideas I had:

- Use mysql database track script execution
- Save pids to file, remove pid when script finished
- Run a simple ps+grep command

Im leaning towards using the ps command method since seems to be the easier to code. Does someone knows a better method?

Comment: How are you running every 30 seconds when cron only supports granularity to the minute? Can you talk about what you are actually trying to achieve, as this sort of approach might be avoided altoghether.

Comment: why not just creating a file for each instance? for example I want 1 instance at a time maximum. I create one file. When cron starts - if file exists - not run task. If does not exist - create file, run task, delete file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, your best bet would be the ps+grep command.

Both MySQL and pid solutions would work but there's always the chance that the script -for whatever reason- dies before it's finished thus leaving you with a counter that doesn't represent the number of scripts running at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Using "ps u":

```
if(ifFirstInstance()==false){
    echo "ERROR: script already running.\n";
    die;
    }

//continue here

function ifFirstInstance(){
    $basename = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    ob_start();
    system("ps u", $return); 
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $pieces = count(explode($basename, $result)); 
    $pieces--;
    if($pieces < 2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
    }
```